# Comparing background position using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to compare the obtained position with  `-33px -4px`

This is the code i have written but its not working.

```
var position = $("#"+theid).css( "background-position" );

if ( position == '33px -73px'){

    $("#"+theid).css({'background-position': '-33px -4px'});
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: "It's not working" is never likely to get you a great response. Help us to help you. WHAT is not working? Error messages? Etc etc.

Comment: Your code is ok, the problem is in the context of the code; right click in your browser, click 'Inspect element' and check the console messages.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this is the right way to do this .. But this works :)

```
 var position = $("#"+theid).css( "background-position" ).split(" ");
 var xPos = position[0],
 yPos = position[1];


 if ( xPos == '-33px' ){
 if ( yPos == '-73px' ){
$("#"+theid).css({'background-position': '-33px -4px'});
  }

  }
```